# Getting files off GitHub

Tags: github

I would like to try the application from a GitHub repository. I'm very new to coding and GitHub. I can't seem to figure out how to actually use the code provided so I can run the application. The address is
https://github.com/chuangag/room-booking-app

I have followed the steps in the Readme file. In Terminal (I'm on Mac) I ran the following

```
$ pip install flask
$ pip install flask-wtf
$ pip install flask-sqlalchemy
$ pip install flask-migrate
$ pip install flask-login
```

There also appears to be some changes to add this

```
$ pip install flask-migrate
$ pip install flask-login
```

All of that seems to have worked well

I then did (seems to be ok? no error came up)

```
$ export FLASK_APP=lab2.py
```

And

```
$ flask db init
```

And that's where I get:

```
Usage: flask db init [OPTIONS]
Error: Could not import "lab2".
```

So it seems "lab2", which I can see in the repository, never gets installed or something like that? I have tried running the entire repository through PyCharm but nothing happened...

I have no idea which parts of code I need to get from the posting and where to run them.

Comment: Did you clone the repository?

Comment: Please share more detials. How is the problem you describe related to Github itself?

Comment: Have you made use of https://docs.github.com/en/get-started

Comment: Yes, I have cloned the repository. I have followed all the steps in the readme file. I just keep getting the error: Could not import "lab2".